# Apache on Solaris 11: connection from localhost works, remote host's connection gets reset by peer

Tags: apache, configuration, solaris

I have configured an apache2 server on Solaris 11, which seems to work well since it shows the correct behaviour when I access it on localhost. However, any remote connection is reset by peer. I already disabled the ipfilter firewall to no avail. A telnet connection from a remote host on port 80 works fine, though:

```
$ telnet myserver.com 80
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to myserver.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

With curl I run into this "connection reset by peer" error:

```
$ curl http://myserver.com
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm totally out of ideas where to look for a fix... Any hint is highly appreciated! The configuration of the server's operating system is an "out-of-the-box" installation, as is the Apache installation (although I use the apache from openCSW, but this didn't make a difference). Is there any security context which filters http connections from remote hosts where I could have a look at? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the apache configuration file to see if it is listening on the "localhost" ? Check the Listen or BindAddress directives. Also try to see if http://ip_address works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked all my configs. No "localhost" in it, and not BindAddress directive. However, your comment has given me another idea: I have copied all configuration of port 80 to port 8000 (Listen *:8000, NameVirtualHost *:8000) and set up a virtual host on this port 8000. Surprisingly, this went fine! All no problem. Therefore, I believe that the apache config is alright but that there's some other service in Solaris running which messes with port 80 (ipfilter is already disabled, can't be the firewall then, I believe, but must be some other service...).

Comment: Glad you found a workaround ; the issue is still a bit of a mystery :)

Comment: Well, kind of a workaround, not sure if I should stick to it and configure NAT in the ipfilters... By snooping on the network interface I found that after the initial sync, sync ack, ack packets the client(!) sends a reset signal, then an ack push (GET / HTTP/1.1), and receives a reset from the server -- and that's the signal which makes curl reporting this error. Very weird. Still investigating...